# I want to express I3 as the subject of an equation which is independent of I2 and I1. How do I solve these system of equations?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have a few equations that relate some variables. I want to express I3 as the subject.

1. -$\frac{V}{s}$ + $\frac{I1}{Cs}$ - $\frac{I2}{Cs}$ = 0
2. $\frac{I2}{Cs}$ + $\frac{I2}{Cs}$ + I2Ls - $\frac{I3}{Cs}$ - $\frac{I1}{Cs}$ = 0
3. $\frac{I3}{Cs}$ + I3R - $\frac{I2}{Cs}$ = 0

Could anyone show me the entire derivation for I3 in terms of C,L,s and R and independent of (doesn't include) I2 and I1?

I have tried the Wolfram equations solver - https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=systems+of+equations+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation1%22%7D+-%3E%22-v%2Fs+%2B+x%2F%28Cs%29+-+y%2F%28Cs%29+%3D+0%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation2%22%7D+-%3E%22y%2F%28Cs%29+%2B+yLs+%2B+y%2F%28Cs%29+-+z%2F%28Cs%29+-+x%2F%28Cs%29+%3D+0%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation3%22%7D+-%3E%22z%2F%28Cs%29+%2B+zR+-+y%2F%28Cs%29%22 - but I am not sure which one is right.

Comment: Add all equations.

Comment: What did you trie? first multiply everything by CS,

Comment: System is linear with respect to $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$. Then this system can be solved analytically with standard methods of linear algebra. After getting solution one can drop $I_1$ and $I_2$ off and leave with $I_3$.

Comment: Add the first two equations, leaving an equation with only $I_2$ and $I_3$. Solve for $I_2$ in terms of $I_3$. Substitute this for $I_2$ in the third equation leaving an equation with only $I_3$ in it